# Teradata sql substring a long expression and generate new columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I got long expression for each row, the length of the expression is vary, the 'item id' is different and not in the same order either. I know a way to do substring, but I do not know how to get the result I want. Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

Table:

Row 1:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<Data>
     <Item id="DDD">
         <!±DATA±444»»>
     </Item>
     <Item id="BBB">
         <!±DATA±222»»>
     </Item>
     <Item id="CCC">
         <!±DATA±333»»>
     </Item>
     ...
</Data>
```

Row 2:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?><Data><Item id="BBB"><!±DATA±022»»></Item><Item id="CCC"><!±DATA±033»»></Item><Item id="DDD"><!±DATA±044»»></Item>…<Item id="AAA"><!±DATA±011»»></Item>….</Item></Data>
```

Row 3:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?><Data><Item id="AAA"><!±DATA±001»»></Item><Item id="EEE"><!±DATA±005»»></Item><Item id="DDD"><!±DATA±044»»></Item>…<Item id="CCC"><!±DATA±003»»></Item>….</Item></Data>
```

Desired Result:

```
  ID       AAA     BBB    CCC   DDD   EEE  ...    
   1               222    333   444           ...
   2       011     022    033   044        ...
   3       001            003   044   005  ...
  ...      ...     ...    ...   ...   ...  ...
```

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of posting data in comments section

Comment: Please add the data to the question, is it actually XML?

Comment: Sorry accidently published it before review. The question is fullfilled now. I assume it needs to find the longest expression and then substring? Longest expression could have 'AAA' to 'LLL'...

Comment: @dnoeth I think it is xml data. It’s in a Teradata table, shown as a whole piece of text in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/GKc0DE/1) for each column:

```
RegExp_Substr(x,'<Item id="AAA">\s*<!±DATA±\K.+?(?=»»>)', 1,1,'i') AS AAA,
RegExp_Substr(x,'<Item id="BBB">\s*<!±DATA±\K.+?(?=»»>)', 1,1,'i') AS BBB,
...
```

It looks for an exact match of `<Item id="AAA">`, followed by any space characters, followed by `*<!±DATA±` and then extracts the following characters up to the `»»>`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dnoeth, as always. I used RegExp_Substr for a simple regular expression once, should thought this :). Thanks!